# insert a python dict in a PSQL using psycopg2

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, psycopg2

I want to insert the following python dictionary to a postgres database table that has the same columns names as dictionary keys and I have tried the following code

```
import psycopg2
import sys, os
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import pandas.io.sql as psql

# Set up a connection to the postgres server.
try:
    conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname='asd' user='asd' host='asd' password='asd'")
except:
    print ("I am unable to connect to the database")


cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("""set search_path to asd;""")


entry = {
    'pat_id': '100356',
    'event_id': '56',
     'subevent_id': '12324',
       'amount': '6543',
        'unit': 'm'}


cur.execute(""" INSERT INTO drugsdoc(pat_id,event_id,subevent_id,amount,unit) VALUES(%(pat_id)s,%(event_id)s,%(subevent_id)s,%(amount)s,%(unit)s)""",entry)
```

and I get the following error when executing the code

> DataError: malformed array literal: "m"
>   LINE 1: ...ent_id,amount,unit) VALUES('100356','56','12324','6543','m')                                                                   ^
>   DETAIL:  Array value must start with "{" or dimension information.

so what might be the issue and is there a way to make the process of inserting dict entries easier (meaning matching columns names to dict keys and adding values accordingly automatically)

Comment: could you share the description of the table `drugsdoc` ?

Comment: columns // pat_id (bigint) , event_id (bigint) , subevent_id (bigint) , amount (bigint) , unit (char[])

Comment: So `unit` is defined as an array, is it ok ? If possible, you can change `'unit': 'm'` to `'unit': ['m']`